# Better way to stream videio

Tags: ios, avfoundation, nsoutputstream, live-video

Currently I am using `AVFoundation` to grab frames from iPhone camera then turn them to a `UIImage` then I transport it through the `NSOutputStream` I send it to my other device.

Unfortunately I get crashes from most likely too much memory as it hits 300mb at one point.

**My question:** Is there a better way to do this or some other method that would make it stop crashing or have less of a delay between when I send an image as when I get the image on the other device?  Or can I make it like a lifestream where it is almost like a video on the receiving device?

```
    - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
    didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
           fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
    {

        @autoreleasepool {


        UIImage *image = [self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer]; 

        [_room broadcastChatMessage:image fromUser:@"self"];

             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                 [_imgView setImage:image];
             });

        }   
        // < Add your code here that uses the image >
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the best options to stream video from an iOS device is to record an H264 video and extract the NAL units (they represent slices of frames) from the movie file on the disk (using `AVFoundation`) and send them across the network using your protocol of choice.  You can see an example of this in action at https://github.com/jamesghurley/VideoCore/blob/master/transforms/iOS/H264Encode.mm. The latency is quite low using this technique.

However playing back that content on another iOS device is...complicated.  You could use FFMpeg to play it back in real-time, or if you can accept some delay (3-4 seconds) you can set up an HTTP proxy and serve the NAL units via HLS.  That is also a complex procedure, but there may be a library available to do it.

EDIT:  Updating this answer a bit.  There is now a class in iOS 8 called `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer` that can take H.264 NAL units directly as input.